# How to check if UILocalNotification is fired

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am presenting `UILocalNotification` in my app which generally runs in the background. Earlier, I could determine whether users interacted with the notification through logs of `didReceiveLocalNotification`. However, when this log is missing..some of my users say that they did not receive a notification in the first place to interact with it.

Is there a way to determine if the notifications were fired for sure (while the app is running in the background), irrespective of the user noticing it?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created an instance of UILocalNotification, you schedule it using one of two methods of the UIApplication class: scheduleLocalNotification: or presentLocalNotificationNow:. The former method use the fire date to schedule delivery; the latter method presents the notification immediately, regardless of the value of fireDate.
If you schedule the notification using scheduleLocationNotification method, you can create a property of NSDate which will store the date, when you want the notification to be fired, assign that date to your local notification fireDate property. And observe your's system date against the local notification's date. If the system date overlaps the notification's date, then you can be sure that the notification is fired.

It's the only way I can think of, there is no such property or method exposed in the iOS SDK, which can tell if the local notification is fired for sure.

Comment: I'm doing `presentLocalNotification` in my code, but still `didReceiveLocalNotification` is not getting called sometimes.